# Cannot scroll in terminal when connected to ssh server in kde plasma

Tags: ssh, kde, konsole

I am using a ssh connection for remote development. I am using either konsole application in kde or terminator application to connect to ssh.

when I use them normally, I can scroll in them normally to see command output. But, when connected to ssh this goes away. I have tried all the settings but I cannot seem to scroll when connected to server.